# Insert element in specific index of dynamic array with different lengths

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, mapping

Excuse the beginners question, I am still very new to javascript.

**Background**:

I am building a chart that needs to have 2 different arrays but their length must match. In order to get these arrays to match in length, I need to determine values that match and values that don't using dates (this is already accomplished - just giving insight!)

**Problem**:

I need to create a new array that has the same length as array 2 (example below), while  keeping the existing data from array 1.

For example:
The array that I want to append to looks something like this:

```
[1, 5, 10, 35, ...etc]
```

And has a length of 20.

The other array (the one where I've mapped values that match/do-not) looks like this:

```
[{date, matched: false}, {date, matched: true}, {date, matched: true}, {date, matched: false}, ...etc]
```

And has a length of 30.

Basically, what I am trying to do is for every value where matched = false, I wish to insert a 0 in the first array (or create a new array where the value = 0). However, where matched is true, I wish to keep the existing value in the first array.. I am struggling with using loops as the lengths and indexes are different amongst the two.

Can anyone please provide some insight on how to achieve this?

Thanks! :D

Comment: So if `matched` is false, you want to replace the corresponding value in the first array with 0? Or you want to insert a brand new value at that index?

Comment: There is no corresponding in the first array. I'd like to add a 0

Comment: Add a 0 where? To the front? To the back? To a specific index?

Comment: How are these two arrays related then? What value in the first array do you want to keep if `matched` is `true`?

Comment: not trying to sound mean I'm just trying to understand so I can help you solve :D

Comment: To a specific index. If there's no match, it should be 0 at that index. Otherwise it should take the existing values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind, but you can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (grabbing the index) to find whether or not to return the actual value, or zero.

```
array1.map((a,i) => array2[i].matched ? a : 0)
```

```js
let array1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
let array2 = [{date:'2022/04/25', matched: false}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: false},{date:'2022/04/25', matched: false}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: false},{date:'2022/04/25', matched: false}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: false},{date:'2022/04/25', matched: false}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: false},{date:'2022/04/25', matched: false}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: false},{date:'2022/04/25', matched: false}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: false},{date:'2022/04/25', matched: false}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: true}, {date:'2022/04/25', matched: false}] 
let matched = array1.map((a,i) => array2[i].matched ? a : 0);
console.log(matched)
```

Comment: This is extremely close to what I need - but the issue is array2 has a longer length than array1. (In my case, array2 has a length of 30 - whereas array1 with the values is only 19)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/UqMCryswz_q4

Comment: This uses array1 as the incrementor - so the final array will be as long as array1.

Comment: Gotcha, I am looking to have it the opposite - where the dates can add to the array (aka - array2 is the incrementer). I appreciate your help nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

What happens when array2, an array of objects, finds false values of *matched* for which there is no index in array 1? What value is stored in array1 when array2 is greater and *matched* true

```
arr1 [1, 5, 10, 35]
//    0  1   2   3

arr2 [
  {date, matched: false},
  {date, matched: true}, 
  ....,
  {date, matched: false} // indice 30
];

arr1 [0,5,10,35,undefined?,null?,another_data?,0]
```

You can use a for loop but forEach() is simpler, let's see!

```
array2.forEach((element,index)=>{
  // Body of the loop and this code is executed for each element
  if(!element.matched){
    // at each iteration index represents the position of the element en array2
    array1[index] = 0;
  }
})
```

The code walks the array of objects through each *element* and its *index*, then at each iteration we check the *matched* value of each *element* ({matched:true,..}).

If *matched* is false (!true) then in the *index* position that has *element* in array2 we will assign 0 in array1.

The downside of this is that only false values are set, which is going to leave an array with *undefined* values.

Another option if you only want to keep the length of array1 could be to iterate over this array and not array2

```
array1.forEach((element,index)=>{
  if(!array2[index].matched) array1[index] = 0;
});
```

This way array1 keeps its length but we discard the rest of the elements of array2.

Note that I only use *index* and not *element*, I could have set the value of *element* to 0 instead of *array1[index]* which is the same in the end, but I wanted to be more pedagogical. Since we are not interested in element, let's use a common for.

```
for(let index = 0; index < array1.length; index++){
  if(!array2[index].matched) array1[index] = 0;
}
```

But it all depends on what you are going to do with the leftover values of array2.

Now if you want to store a value in the *undefined* positions of array1 for which matched==true, then use an else in the condition.